# The correct case&format of variable and methods and for Python

Tags: python, camelcasing, pascalcasing

So I know some languages have expected conventions.

PHP - `underscore_case()`  [for the most part, lolo]

Java - `camelCase()`

C# - `PascalCase()`

etc.

What's the "Pythonic" naming convention?  I know it doesn't matter in the end but just wondering if there is a "best practice" way that most modules are done in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two words: [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

PEP 8 is the (de facto) Python style guide. Some highlights from this document (I left some stuff out on purpose; go read the original document for the ins and outs):

- **Package and Module Names**: All-lowercase names. Underscores can be used in the module name if it improves readability.
- **Class Names**: Almost without exception, class names use the CapWords convention.*
- **Global Variable Names**: The conventions are about the same as those for functions.
- **Function Names**: Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability. mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that's already the prevailing style (e.g. `threading.py`), to retain backwards compatibility.
- **Method Names and Instance Variables**: Lowercase with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability. Use one leading underscore only for non-public methods and instance variables.
- **Constants**: Written in all capital letters with underscores separating words.  Examples include.

Comment: @Stephan, Nice answer, and nice that this is just the one that took you over the 10K level!

Comment: @mjv: thanks :) It was actually another answer that helped me over the 10K, but it could have been one even before that, had the OP not accepted the answer before upvoting it. I reached my reputation cap for today at 9999 (made a screenshot :), so any points above that are due to accepted answers.

Answer (score 5):

Read [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

It's a style guide for Python code, written by Python's creator, Guido van Rossum.

Incidentally, the answer to your question is to use `underscore_case` for variables and function names, and `PascalCase` for classes.

Comment: Wow - so I answered first, but my edit/expansion makes it look like I answered second.   Is that new?

Answer (score 1):

Seven words: [Google Summer of Code Python Style Guide](http://code.google.com/p/soc/wiki/PythonStyleGuide)

> *Note that some naming conventions differ from PEP8 and instead follow the original Google Python Style guide from which this style guide originated.*
>
> - "Internal" means internal to a module or protected or private within a class.
>     Prepending a single underscore (_) has some support for protecting module variables and functions (not included with import * from).
> - Prepending a double underscore (__) to an instance variable or method effectively serves to make the variable or method private to its class (using name mangling).
> - Place related classes and top-level functions together in a module. Unlike Java, there is no need to limit yourself to one class per module. However, make sure the classes and top-level functions in the same module have high cohesion.
> - Use CapWords for class names, but lower_with_under.py for module names.
>
> **Naming examples**
>
> - Packages: `lower_with_under`
> - Modules:    `lower_with_under`, `_lower_with_under`
> - Classes:    `CapWords,` `_CapWords`
> - Exceptions: `CapWords`
> - Functions:  `firstLowerCapWords()`, `_firstLowerCapWords()`
> - Global/Class Constants: `CAPS_WITH_UNDER`, `_CAPS_WITH_UNDER`
> - Global/Class Variables: `lower_with_under`, `_lower_with_under`
> - Instance Variables: `lower_with_under`, `_lower_with_under` (protected) or `__lower_with_under` (private)
> - Method Names:   `firstLowerCapWords()`, `_firstLowerCapWords()` (protected) or `__firstLowerCapWords()` (private)
> - Function/Method Parameters: `lower_with_under`
> - Local Variables:    `lower_with_under`